# how else works in python?

Tags: python, algorithm, if-statement, markov-chains

I'm writing a code where output depends on previous input. Let's imagine I choose magic stones which are labeled 0 and 1 and I pick them from a sack. For the first pick chances that I get 0 or 1 are 50/50 but if I pick stone 1, chances that I'll pick stone 1 next is 70% and chances that I pick stone 0 is 30%. If I pick stone 0, there is 60% chance that I pick stone 0 next time and 40% chance that I pick stone 1.
Here's some code

```
import random
ones = 0
zeros = 0
a = random.randint(0 , 100)
stone = 0
if a > 50: 
    stone = 1
else: 
    stone = 0
for i in range(100):
    if stone == 1:
        ones+= 1
        a = random.randint(0 , 100)
        if a > 30:
            stone = 1
        else:
            stone = 0
    if stone == 0:
        zeros+= 1
        a = random.randint(0 , 100)
        if a > 40:
            stone = 0
        else:
            stone = 1
        
    
print( ones)
print(zeros)
```

The problem is that ones and zeros don't add up to 100 but if I replace 'if stone == 0' with 'else', everything works fine. Why does such strange thing happen? Aren't those two conditions the same?

Comment: You alter the value of `stone` inside your `if` block. So rechecking `stone` in another `if` statement is different from using `else`.

Comment: there are only 2 conditions when stone can change that is when stone is either equal to 1 or 0. So if I write else, how is that different from writing if stone == 0 as long as there are just two conditions? As far as a thought I knew, else was the same as !=(some value here) but now I replaced if stone == 0 with if stone !=1 and I got wrong answer once again.  I'm really confused at this point about why else works as it does.

Comment: @bearthum - multiple people have pointed out the same problem with your code and more have agreed with them. You would do well to step back and consider why you might be wrong in your assertions, instead of continuing to look for evidence why you're right.

Answer (score 0):

The first part of your for-loop has this:

```
    if stone == 1:
        ones+= 1
        a = random.randint(0 , 100)
        if a > 30:
            stone = 1
        else:
            stone = 0
```

So, if `stone` equals 1, and `a` then isn't greater than 30, `stone` becomes 0.

On then do you execute your second if statement:

```
    if stone == 0:
        zeros+= 1
        a = random.randint(0 , 100)
        if a > 40:
            stone = 0
        else:
            stone = 1
```

If you use an `else` instead, that never gets executed if the first condition was true and it always gets executed if the first conditions was not true.

Comment: yeah but the same logic can be applied without else. let's say stone == 1 and then becomes 0, that means stone == 1 is false and stone == 0 is true.

Comment: That doesn't matter - the point is you're executing two separate `if` statements, one after the other. But the code that gets executed in the first affects the condition of the second. This is not what you want, you need them to be mutually exclusive, relying on either one outcome or the other.

Answer (score 0):

No actually if in the first if condition the value of `stone` changes to `0` then the condition `if stone == 0`  becomes `True` which leads to the possibility that within one iteration of your for-loop both counters can count up by 1.

Use

```
else
```

Or

```
elif stone==0:
```

Comment: `elif stone==0` won't work for the same reason.

Comment: yeah. When I printed values of ones and zeros inside the loop, both counters increased but I don't understand why that happens. stone can't be 0 and 1 at the same time. If stone changes to 0, the program jumps to execute this: if stone == 0  and after that zeros increase by one and ones stay the same

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for responding. I finally figured out the problem. It seems that when I write if and then else, the checking of 0 and 1 occurs only once because of structure of if/else statement and if I write if and then also if, the checking happens twice. That was the reason why ones and zeros both increased in the same iteration.